# Transposing a data range and replacing a column with query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a data set that looks like the one below in the image. And I'm trying to turn it into the expected table in the image as well. A simple transpose doesn't seem to be working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the upper-leftmost blank cell in your first chart sits at A1:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(FILTER({SPLIT(A2:A&"|"&C1,"|"),B2:C},A2:A<>""),"Select Col1, Col2, SUM(Col4) GROUP BY Col1, Col2 PIVOT Col3"))`

I can't teach all about QUERY here. But some tips:

`FILTER` filters in just non-blank rows from the source range.

`SPLIT(A2:A&"|"&C1,"|")` concatenates every value in the original Column A with a pipe symbol followed by the C1 value ("Q1"), which is then split at the pipe symbol to form two columns: one with sessions and one containing the repeated "Q1" as show in your first two columns of your desired result report.

The `GROUP BY` portion of the `QUERY` (which includes two columns here) tells what will run down the left side of the results.

The aggregate function `SUM` in the `QUERY` tells which data should be grouped per header.

The `PIVOT` portion of the `QUERY` determines what should run along the top as headers.